# Valgrind hangs after program ends inside docker after a specific dbus call

Tags: docker, cross-compiling, valgrind, glib, dbus

I'm trying to use valgrind to analyze a source code for an ARM embedded board. I managed to make it work inside a docker container for most processes, but unfortunately one call of a GLIB function wont let valgrind show me the report after the process has exited and valgrind hangs. The call is `g_bus_get_sync()`. Here is a minimal code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GError *error = NULL;
    GDBusConnection *conn = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, &error);
        if (conn == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR !\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("OK\n");
        return 0;
}
```

The weird thing is that on normal host (not with SYSTEM DBus shared between host and container), everything works normally, and valgrind shows the reports. But unfortunately inside the container, the valgrind process just hangs (I waited a day to be sure) after having printed "OK".

I can run normally the program without valgrind and everything works perfectly, the process terminates normally.

Also I managed to make this part of code with valgrind work ON the board with enough RAM, but I really need to run valgrind on our whole big code inside a docker because RAM of the board is not big enough. It shows that the problem doesn't come from GLib version (2.48.1) or valgrind version (3.12.0) since the cross-builded image inside the container is the image I ran on the target where everything worked. It seems that the problem is directly linked to docker...

Here is the docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  hub:
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    image: my-image:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=:0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/dbus/:/var/run/dbus/:z
```

The image is crossbuilded using `docker buildx` :

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --load -t my-image .
```

Also with a dbus monitor I noticed that everything works normally (Hello method call, and NameAcquired signal sent...)

I tried to use gdb, everything works, and valgrind with vgdb and when the C program ends, vgdb doesn't show anything.

EDIT 1 : The DBus calls (SYSTEM) inside the program are working normally. When I change SYSTEM to SESSION, valgrind no longer hangs and works perfectly...

Comment: Docker and ARM. No-one is going to able to help you with that. You're on your own. Try looking at README_DEVELOPERS and debugging Valgrind yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by calling `g_dbus_connection_close()`.